# FluentValidation NotEmpty and EmailAddress example

Tags: c#, validation, refactoring, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation with a login form. The email address field is

*Required* and *Must be a valid email address*.

I want to display a custom error message in both cases.

The code I have working is:

```
RuleFor(customer => customer.email)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage("Email address is required.");

RuleFor(customer => customer.email)
    .EmailAddress()
    .WithMessage("A valid email address is required.");
```

The above code does work and shows (2) different error messages.
Is there a better way of writing the multiple error message for one field?

**UPDATE - WORKING**

Chaining and add `.WithMessage` **after** each requirement worked.

```
RuleFor(customer => customer.email)
    .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Email address is required.")
    .EmailAddress()
        .WithMessage("A valid email address is required.");
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just chain them together, it's called Fluent Validation for a reason.

```
RuleFor(s => s.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email address is required")
                     .EmailAddress().WithMessage("A valid email is required");
```